# javascript. innerHTML clearing content already pushed to an array

Tags: javascript

The issue I am having is that when I push "con" into pagesArr, it stores it correctly. After the con.innerHTML = "" however, i inspect the pagesArr array and the content is gone.

```
function storePages(con){
  //loop through data
  for( index; index < dataLen; index++){
    appending(con,jsonArray[index]); //append the data to the container
    //compare menu container height to wrapper height
    if(con.offsetHeight >= (wrapper.offsetHeight - 150)){                
      pagesArr.push(con);  
      con.innerHTML = "";       
      break;
    }
  }
  //call function while we still have data
  while(index < dataLen){      
    storePages(con);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are pushing DOM Elements into `pagesArr`. You made the `.innerHTML` get emptied out on each DOM Element, what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are not stored inside variables, they are linked. Manipulating the object will effect all variables, linked to it. Basically, to store a separate object, you gotta make a copy of it.